# Which is an alternative to the service that Google Calendar offer for the free SMS notifications?

Tags: google-calendar, sms

Which is an alternative to the service that Google Calendar offer for the free SMS notifications?

Comment: Is there a chance you could consider this question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Remember the Milk?

http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/reminders/setreminders.rtm